# Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: qt, qt4

Consider this thread, it acts like a timer, send some packet to serial:

```
void PlCThead::run()
{
    while(1)
    {
        const char str[]={UPDATE_PACKET};

        QByteArray  built;
        built.append(0x02);
        built.append(0x05);
        built.append(0x03);

        emit requestForWriteAndReceive(built);

        msleep(100);
    }
}
```

emit works fine, it goes inside the slot, there, it writes only 78 or char x to serial instead of a packet of 3 bytes.

```
bool RS::rs_ThreadPlcDataAqustn(QByteArray byteArray)
{
    QByteArray rd15Bytes;

    char *data = byteArray.data();
    int len = byteArray.length();

    if(!rs_serialWrite(data, len))
    {
        qDebug() << "Failure:( rs_dataqustn: rs_plcWrite(data, len)";
        emit plc_port_dscntd();
        return false;
    }
}

bool RS::rs_serialWrite(char* buff, size_t length)
{  
    int tries;

    int len;

    tries = 0;

    QByteArray built((char*)buff, length);

    qDebug() << built.toHex();


            len = write(fd, buff, length);

            qDebug() << len;

            qDebug() << strerror(errno);

            return true;
}
```

this is how fd created:

```
fd = open(portPath, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY | O_NONBLOCK, S_IWUSR | S_IRUSR | S_IXUSR);
```

this is how the thread created in mainwindow:

```
rs_plc->rs_plcOpenPort((char *)"/dev/ttyS0"); /*/dev/ttyS3*/

PlCThead *thread = new PlCThead();
connect(thread, SIGNAL(requestForWriteAndReceive(QByteArray)), rs_plc, SLOT(rs_ThreadPlcDataAqustn(QByteArray )));
thread->start();
```

rs_plc is a private member of MainWindow.

`strerror` returns back this warning:

```
> Resource temporarily unavailable
```

any ideas? this code works fine with timers, it has been checked and tested accurately, but now i need to add this thread instead of the timer. Thanks

Comment: why do you transmit a `char str` and not a `QByteArray` in the signal?

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't complete enough for a full diagnosis since you aren't showing how `fd` is created, how the threads are set up (which you say is part of the problem), etc.

But...  your `resource temporarily unavailable` line is a big hint.  The write() function isn't succeeding to write everything because it's returning an error (probably `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK`).  The `fd` file descriptor is attached to something that either has a small buffer, no buffer, or a buffer which is already full.  And it's full, and it's the applications job to not send it anything else until it can handle it.  A common thing to do there is to sleep and then try the write again if the error code is `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK`.

But, you said it's returning 3, which actually indicates "no error" too.  And if that's the case then the error string won't be referring to write itself, and something else set `errno` previously.  (which could have been `write` itself in the past).

In short, if this is getting called more than once (likely) you probably need to watch out for writing too fast (and it looks like a serial buffer, which definitely falls into the category of easy-to-fill-the-buffer).

In short: if it's not writing all the bytes to the `fd` than you want, it's because it can't handle more than that.

This likely has absolutely nothing to do with `qt` by the way.  It's all about the `write()` call.

Comment: i updated my code above, I still do not understand what the problem is

Comment: Not sure if this has nothing to do with qt, with only 3 lines of code i'm loading URL, and it stucks! on 3 vm's and 1 physical machine, with exact same error in strace, what I'm missing?